# Visual Studio replace c# code when compiling

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-4.0, t4

I am not familiar with T4 templates or any Visual Studio plugins regarding code replacement at CompileTime.

I have the following code:

```
[Localizable(true)]
[AmbientValue(true)]
[Description("customized")]
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    [Localizable(true)]
    [AmbientValue(true)]
    [Description("customized")]
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Because the code is always the same and redudant I want to simplify the code like this:

```
@myTemplate
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    @myTemplate
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Anyone aware of a technique in Visual Studio to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.postsharp.net/

Comment: If by "the code is always the same and redudant" [sic], you mean that you have multiple classes with that pattern you can let them inherit from `Form1`

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you want to do, [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) or any other AOP Framework could be a clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on [polymorphism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx). The easiest way to accomplish what you're trying to do is by letting your classes inherit from a common parent that has the attributes you want. Just remember that if you override a method from your base class, you have to re-declare your attributes (although you can use an [`[AttributeProvider]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.attributeproviderattribute.aspx) to suggest attributes for an indexer or property).

The short answer to your question is "no". You can (with enough of an effort) but it's simply not worth it. It's better to simply inherit the attributes.